# How can I add a local framework to a custom React Native native module in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have created a custom native module for React Native using [create-react-native-library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob). I have a local framework that is closed source and does not use a remote git repository. How can I add this framework as a dependency to my React Native native module? All docs I can find rely on there being a remote repo / pod and or an actual app (not just a module) to add it to.